# Comment traduire/exprimer le(s) « black hole(s) » d'une chaîne logistique ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, commerce

Comment traduire ou exprimer ces « organizational/physical goods/data/finding and reconciling... black hole(s)... in your procurement process / plugging black holes with enterprise systems » ([source de ces emplois](https://www.procurious.com/procurement-news/dont-let-black-holes-warp-your-procurement-process)) ? Il s'agit de jargon de logistique d'affaires basé sur une analogie avec le phénomène en astrophysique...

- Utilise-t-on « black hole » ou « trou noir » dans ce genre de domaine
  ?
- Quels sont des termes synonymes qui correspondent à cette analogie
  et qui sont employés dans ce genre de contexte ?